# Let $f(x) = \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor$ for $x \ge 0.$ Find all $x \ge 0$ such that $f(x) = 5.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $f(x) = \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor$ for $x \ge 0.$

Find all $x \ge 0$ such that $f(x) = 5.$

I found that $f(2)=4$ and $f(3)=9$ so $f(x)=5$ should be in $x \in (2,3).$
But I found that $f(x)=4$ also works for this interval, meaning my interval is incorrect.
Could someone help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: Try to write down the definition of the floor function and go step by step until you don't know anymore how to go further. Write this in your question and we will be able to help you find the solution.

Comment: I don't understand ". But I found that ()=4 also works for this interval, meaning my interval is incorrect". The function $f$ need not be constant on intervals $(n, n + 1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x < 2.5$, then $x \lfloor x \rfloor < 5$ so $\lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor < 5$.

If $x \geq 3$, then $x \lfloor x \rfloor \geq 9$ so $\lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor \geq 9$.

If $2.5 \leq x < 3$, then $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$, so $5 \leq x \lfloor x \rfloor < 6$, so $\lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor = 5$.

So the interval is $[2.5, 3)$.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Really appreciate it! :)